# How to select every third element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and styling a card list. The cards have different heights according to their content. I want to add a div.clearfix after every third card.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 card-list">
Card here
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 card-list">
Card here
</div>
```

Problem is I can only manage to get the third, but not the sixth, etc.

```
 $('.card-list:nth-child(5)').after('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Not sure I understand though. The .card-list were not the only elements in my row.

The `$('.card-list:nth-child(3n)')` was not only counting the .card-list but also what came before, even though it didn't have the .card-list class.

I should have checked that earlier, thank you for the help by the way.

Here is what I had :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="title-bullet-small">Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 list-filters">
        Some forms
    </div>
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I had to do in order for the `$('.card-list:nth-child(3n)')` to work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="title-bullet-small">Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 list-filters">
        Some forms
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
    <div class="card-list">
        Card
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amelie, that's an answer to a different question as the original code changed. In such cases the best path is to wrap up the old question by accepting the best answer, and create a new question with the new requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I do it by `filter` function. This is the most safe way in my opinion

```
$('.card-list').filter(function(a){return a%3 == 0;}).after('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select every third item using `3n` like `$('.card-list:nth-child(3n)')`

Comment: This partially works. Except it selects the second element, then goes 3 by 3 as it's supposed to. I don't understand why it affects my second card.

Comment: Are you sure? Check this out http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/yJERQX it works. I don't see selecting the second child. Please explain...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.card-list:nth-child(3n+3)').after('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

Try the above code. see if it works. If it doesn't work can you make a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you:

```
var $clearfix = '<div class="clearfix">clearfix</div>';
$('.card-list:nth-child(3n+0)').append($clearfix);
```